# Do loop not pulling in all data- creating dates

Tags: sas, do-loops

We have a code that we use to create quarterly reports of projects. There is a piece of code, a do loop, that takes the startdate and enddate of each project in our dataset and creates an observation for each month and year that the project took place in. For example if we have a project called "Employment Help" with a startdate value of 01JAN2022 and an enddate value of 01APR2022, the do loop will create 4 observations for this project with the month and year values of 1 2022, 2 2022, 3 2022, and 4 2022. We use this to count how many projects happened during our quarters. We are running into an issue where the do loop is dropping projects and not giving them a month or year value and we are losing projects in our count because of this. The dates are all in the same format.
Here is an example of some data that is pulled in, EXAMPLE 2 is properly pulled into the do loop, EXAMPLE 1 does not get pulled through.

Here is the code:

```
**data test2;
 set users3;
 do i = 0 to (year(enddate)-year(startdate));
  year = year(startdate)+i;
  end;
   do i = 0 to (month(enddate)-month(startdate));
  month = month(startdate)+i;
  drop i;
  output;
   end;
   run;**
```

Comment: Can you include some examples of your start/endate? Specifically ones where it seems to fail?

Comment: It doesn't seem to allow me to paste any info in the question but here is one, Example 1 gets dropped but example 2 does not, and runs normally.
12Oct2021 7Feb2022 EXAMPLE1 PROJECT # STAFF EMAIL INST. COLLEGE   DEMOGRAPHICS                              29Apr2020 8May2020 EXAMPLE 2 PROJECT # STAFF EMAIL INST. COLLEGE   DEMOGRAPHICS

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
data have;
    input project$ startdate:date9. enddate:date9.;
    format startdate enddate date9.;

    datalines;
A 01JAN2022 01APR2022
B 01MAR2022 01JUN2022
C 01NOV2022 01JAN2023
;
run;
```

The third row will fail to run because the difference between the start month number and end month number is negative (1 - 11). Instead of doing two loops, one for year and one for month, do a single loop for all of the months from the start date. Use `intnx()` to generate your months using `startdate` as the reference month. `i` will offset each month from the start date. For example:

```
code                           output
intnx('month', '01JAN2022'd, 0)   01JAN2022
intnx('month', '01JAN2022'd, 1)   01FEB2022
intnx('month', '01JAN2022'd, 2)   01MAR2022
```

Since you're incrementing by exactly one month for each date, you can get the year and month number in a single loop.

```
data want;
    set have;

    do i = 0 to intck('month', startdate, enddate);
        month = month(intnx('month', startdate, i) );
        year  = year(intnx('month', startdate, i) );

        output;
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to handle the cross of years, ie if a project started in 2021 and ended in 2022.

This should get you closer.

```
data have;
input startdate : date9. enddate : date9.;
format startdate enddate date9.;
cards;
01Jan2022 01Apr2022
01Sep2021 01Apr2022
;;;
run;

   data want;
   set have;
   
   nmonths = intck('month', startdate, enddate) +1 ;
   date = startdate;
   do i = 1 to nmonths;
   month = month(date);
   year = year(date);
   date = intnx('month', startdate, i, 'b');
   output;
   end;
   
   run;
```

Comment: Thank you!! I think i just noticed this in my excel sheet.